# Programmatic way to tell if Certificate is a Personal or Root Certificate

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

If I have a certificate (X509Certificate2 object) in C#, is there a way to determine whether the certificate is a personal or root certificate?

When you install a certificate in Windows, it tries to automatically determine what store to place the cert in. Is there a way to determine this using the cert's data, or to install the cert and let .NET determine which store it should be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the the **X509BasicConstraintsExtension.CertificateAuthority** property to identify if a certificate is a certificate authority(not necessarily root, it can also be intermediate). See more info and an example in [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509basicconstraintsextension.certificateauthority(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this works. Do you know of cases where this property would be inaccurate?

Comment: Is there a safe way to identify between Root and Intermediate please?